Which cryptocurrency sites are there on Stack Exchange and everywhere else?
We've got an upcoming close reason about cryptocurrency sites. However, instead of closing down questions we may want to migrate them or point out the resource to the user. That's more helpful than closing them down.
Could we create a community-wiki kind of answer that lists these sites in once place?

Note that we should not downvote off topic questions; most of the users don't seem to be aware that their question is not on topic.

Yes, we can create a list of crypto-currency sites on Stack Exchange and elsewhere. However, I've decided that this list is better hosted at the generic meta pages as wiki answer, as many users of other sites will have the same question. You can find the full list here.
The previous answer has migrated there and has been substantially updated by other users already. Yay!
